# How to change categories on single post is displayed

Tags: wordpress, categories

So currently on a single post the categories associated with that page is the following... **Categories:** Figured, Plain, Plain Sliced, Quartered, Rotary, White.

I need to display the categories in the following manor...

**Color:** White
**Cutting Method:** Plain Sliced, Quartered, Rotary
**Type:** Figured, Plain

Any idea on how to rewrite the php inside the loop of the post content on a single post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I've solved this issue... if anyone else ever wanted to know on how to display categories in this manor, here is the PHP coding.

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$separator = ', ';
if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
  $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

  $cat_color_terms = wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'parent' => 4, // CAT ID FOR COLOR
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids
    )
  );

  $cat_cutting_method_terms = wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'parent' => 8, // CAT ID FOR CUTTING METHOD
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids
    )
  );

  $cat_type_terms = wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'parent' => 9, // CAT ID FOR TYPE
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids
    )
  );

  $cat_color_terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $cat_color_terms ) ), $separator );
  $cat_cutting_method_terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $cat_cutting_method_terms ) ), $separator );
  $cat_type_terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $cat_type_terms ) ), $separator );

  if ( ($cat_color_terms) != 'No categories' ) {
    echo  '<strong>Color:</strong> '.$cat_color_terms;
    echo '<br>';
  }
  if ( ($cat_cutting_method_terms) != 'No categories' ) {
    echo  '<strong>Cutting Method:</strong> '.$cat_cutting_method_terms;
    echo '<br>';
  }
  if ( ($cat_type_terms) != 'No categories' ) {
    echo  '<strong>Type:</strong> '.$cat_type_terms;
  }

} // END IF
```

With each of the wp_list_categories array shows the parent ID category that is associated to the current post. So for example the first one shown here is to display the COLOR name. In the backend of wordpress, in the categories section the main category is called COLOR (parent), and then I have a list of color names as sub-categories. With indicating the PARENT ID number, will display the color name. Even if you have the parent category selected to the post it will still work to display the sub-categories associated to that posting.

For what I've done to display this code, was I created a new template within my theme for displaying the full post (single post). This code in displaying the categories is inside the loop.